# How to align csv file values in listview columns when there is a default value in listview control

Tags: c#

So i have a problem with my alignment when I import a csv file into my listview control

This is the problem:

[image]

The defualt value in the listview control is "Mark" and "Joe".
when i upload a csv file, it inserts the values on the next row on starting at the first column.

The correct output need to be like this:

[image]

The csv values needs to be aligned with the default values Mark and Joe

Note: The values that are inside my dummy csv file are:

asd, 1234

dfg,1234

This is the code that I have constructed so far...

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to import the data from \n " + openFileDialog1.FileName + "?", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
        string csv = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);

        sr.Close();                 

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            var parts = line.Split(',');
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(parts[0]);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(parts[1]);
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks to those experts who are willing to help my simple problem. . .

Comment: Perhaps instead of creating a new `ListViewItem` you could just grab the default ones and add the extra `SubItems`

Comment: Yes. That's what I was also thinking but I'm kind of lost as to how I'm supposed to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to modify the existing items not add new ones, one option could be to keep track of the index and use that to grab the item and add the `SubItems` to that `ListViewItem`

```
int index = 0;
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("");
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    var parts = line.Split(',');
    // TODO: check if the item at index exists first
    var existingItem = listView1.Items[index]; 
    existingItem.SubItems.Add(parts[0]);
    existingItem.SubItems.Add(parts[1]);
    index++;
}
```

NOTE: you should add some error checking around the index or you could get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` if the csv contains more lines than your `ListViewItems` items

Comment: thanks for this and for the explanation. I added an error checking code as you have instructed . Thanks again .